# How to make Jquery redirect with bootstrap label

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap navigation has following code and i want to make when i click label should redirect different pages

```
<li class="btn-group-lst">
 <div id="gender-btn" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">                            
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-select">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        <span>US</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default gender-select">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        <span>UK</span>
    </label>
 </div></li>
```

My j-query is here.

```
$('.gender-select :option1').on('click', function(){
        window.location.href = '<?=site_url('main/us_details')?>';
    });

$('.gender-select :option2').on('click', function(){
        window.location.href = '<?=site_url('main/uk_details')?>';
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<li class="btn-group-lst">
 <div id="gender-btn" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">                            
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" class="gender-select" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        <span>US</span>
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="radio" class="gender-select" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
        <span>UK</span>
    </label>
 </div>
</li>
```

***First assign the gender-select to the radio button "" not to the label.***

*then try this code below!*

```
$('.gender-select').on('click', function(){
        var Selected = $(this).attr('id');
        // Option1 Action
        if (Selected == "option1") {
            window.location.href = '<?=site_url('main/us_details')?>';
        }
        // Option2 Action
        if (Selected == "option2") {
            window.location.href = '<?=site_url('main/uk_details')?>';
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could hold the url within the html for simplicity:

```
<label class="btn btn-default gender-select" data-link="main/us_details">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
    <span>US</span>
</label>

<label class="btn btn-default gender-select" data-link="main/uk_details">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
    <span>UK</span>
</label>

$('.gender-select').on('click', function(){
    var linkRef = $(this).data('link');
    window.location.href = '<?=site_url("' + linkRef + '")?>';
});
```

Comment: var link variable is unused..?? i think this has to be change`window.location.href = '<?=site_url("' + link + '")?>';`

Comment: It's really ok but have changed it anyway